# Shorten/truncate UTF8 string in PHP

Tags: php, string, utf-8, truncate

I need a good fast function that shortens strings to a set length with UTF8 support. Adding trailing '...' at ends is a plus. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming `mb_*` functions installed.

```
function truncate($str, $length, $append = '…') {
  $strLength = mb_strlen($str);

  if ($strLength <= $length) {
     return $str;
  }

  return mb_substr($str, 0, $length) . $append;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/H4MLHj).

Keep in mind this will add one character (the elipsis). If you want the `$append` included in the length that is truncated, just minus the `mb_strlen($append)` from the length of the string you chop.

Obviously, this will also chop in the middle of words.

#### Update

Here is a version that can optionally preserve whole words...

```
function truncate($str, $length, $breakWords = TRUE, $append = '…') {
  $strLength = mb_strlen($str);

  if ($strLength <= $length) {
     return $str;
  }
  
  if ( ! $breakWords) {
       while ($length < $strLength AND preg_match('/^\pL$/', mb_substr($str, $length, 1))) {
           $length++;
       }
  }

  return mb_substr($str, 0, $length) . $append;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/U7e08a).

It will preserve all letter characters up to the first non letter character if the third argument is `TRUE`.

Comment: For some reason this is not shortening anything

Comment: Wouldn’t you want to break this on a word boundary?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to truncate text, so this may be helpful:

```
if (!function_exists('truncate_string')) {
    function truncate_string($string, $max_length) {
        if (mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8') > $max_length){
            $string = mb_substr($string, 0, $max_length, 'UTF-8');
            $pos = mb_strrpos($string, ' ', false, 'UTF-8');
            if($pos === false) {
                return mb_substr($string, 0, $max_length, 'UTF-8').'…';
            }
            return mb_substr($string, 0, $pos, 'UTF-8').'…';
        }else{
            return $string;
        }
    }
}
```

This is something like @alex just posted, but it does not break words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$length = 100;
if(mb_strlen($text, "utf-8") > $length){
$last_space = mb_strrpos(mb_substr($text, 0, $length, "utf-8"), " ", "utf-8");
$text = mb_substr($text, 0, $last_space, "utf-8")." ...";}`

Cheers...